Verify that user agent facebookexternalhit is really Facebook
I'm seeing a lot of hits on my website with the following user agent:
facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)

I'm trying to verify whether it really is from Facebook or a spoofing bot.
Using these these Facebook directions, I ran the following to get the real IPs:
whois -h whois.radb.net -- '-i origin AS32934' | grep ^route

That got me more than 800 IPs. They look a lot like the IPs I'm seeing, but not exactly.
For example, my website hits include:
2a03:2880:12ff:2::face:b00c
2a03:2880:13ff:f::face:b00c
2a03:2880:22ff:4::face:b00c

The whois list includes a lot that start the same, but no exact matches, for example:
2a03:2880:f310::/48
2a03:2880:f132::/48

Is that... close enough? Is there another way to check?

Yes, that is enough to check. The list entries you quote are routing prefixes, showing ownership of an entire block of IP addresses. For example, 2a03:2880:f310::/48 means every IPv6 IP address beginning 2a03:2880:f310:... (the 48 comes from the fact that the first 48 bits are fixed, the rest are open). The routes list you quote from also includes e.g. 2a03:2880::/32 (which is every single IPv6 address beginning 2a03:2880) and 2a03:2880:1000::/36 (which is every address under 2a03:2880:1...); so the IP addresses you quote are all real Facebook IP addresses. [I am also seeing a lot of hits from this bot, all real FB addresses, multiple hits for the same web page in the same second, thousands of requests for unchanging images, it's quite tedious.]
